# Pass SharePoint Credentials to Access Excel File using Interop?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, excel-interop

```
string url = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Project/Shared%20Documents/ExcelSheet.xlsx");

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(url):
```

This prompts me for an email(userid) and password, I know I can pass the password but how do I get the email(userid) in there.

I also have the SharpePoint credentials saved, I intially tried using the SharepointClient but I got as far as being able download the File, I couldn't figure out how to convert it to an Excel workbook to loop through the cells.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Project/"):          
SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

 context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(password)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [Excel Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects) i would propose to utilize [Excel Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sample-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api) which allows to read excel data without any dependencies to external or third party libraries.

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to read *workbook data* from [`Financial Sample.xlsx`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962) sample excel file stored in SharePoint Online `Documents` library

```
var credentials = GetCredentials(userName, password);
var client = new ExcelClient(webUrl, credentials);
var data = client.ReadTable("Shared Documents/Financial Sample.xlsx", "Sheet1","A1", "P500");
JObject table = JObject.Parse(data);
int idx = 0;
foreach(var row in table["rows"])
{
     if(idx == 0)
     {
        //skip header
     }
     else
     {
        //get cell values
        var segment = row[0]["v"] as JValue;
        var country = row[1]["v"] as JValue;
        Console.WriteLine("Segment: {0}, Country: {1}", segment.Value,country.Value);
     }
     idx++;
}
```

where

[`WebClient` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) is utilized to consume Excel Services REST

```
public class ExcelClient : WebClient
{

    public ExcelClient(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials)
    {
        BaseAddress = webUrl;
        Credentials = credentials;
        Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    }

    public string ReadTable(string fileUrl, string sheetName, string cellStart,string cellEnd, string format="json")
    {

        var endpointUrl = BaseAddress + string.Format("/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/{0}/Model/Ranges('{1}!{2}|{3}')?$format={4}", fileUrl,sheetName,cellStart,cellEnd,format);
        return DownloadString(endpointUrl);
    }

}
```

and [`SharePointOnlineCredentials` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) to access SharePoint Online resources via user credentials

```
static ICredentials GetCredentials(string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password)
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }
    return new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
}
```

**Results**

[image]

[image]

**References**

- [Sample URI For Excel Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sample-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api)
- [Requesting Excel workbook data from SharePoint Server using OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/requesting-excel-workbook-data-from-sharepoint-server-using-odata)

Comment: How about writing to Excel? And I cannot use Graph API because cannot have app id configured due of company security policy :(